# developing an R package, defining the date of its dependencies

Tags: r

I'm developing an R package and defining its dependencies in the DESCRIPTION file. To avoid incompatibilities with newer versions of other packages, is there the option to define the date of the packages to import, similarly to *checkpoint*? I'm looking for something like

```
Imports:
    dplyr ("2017-01-01")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you cannot do that -- R package semantics are simply different.  But you can use your own repository, and define appropriate versions of those packages these. The drat package can help.

Comment: Wouldn't `dplyr (>= 0.5.0)` suffice here?

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to set a maximum version for all the packages based on their release date. dplyr (== 0.5.0) would to the trick, but I'd need to manually define the version of each package corresponding to the given date.